# a array contains a string or not with Expression in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

With expression, I want to know that whether a string is contained in a array or not.

case code is [here](https://github.com/wnczwl369/sample-code/blob/master/Expression-Linghtning-Component).

Is there any way to fix it or a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible in an expression.

You'll want to use another component in the iteration. In that component you can use JavaScript for that logic.